# Word for version number that counts backwards

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

In versioning (e.g. software, documents, ...) a "version" or "revision" typically starts at 0 or 1 and increments with every change. The newest document is the one with highest version number.

I have a system where it is beneficial to do it the opposite way, newest document is saved as version 0 and the version of all the older documents is incremented. However, calling it a "version" may be misleading because it behaves opposite of the usual. Is there better word? Two words could work too.

Note that this is not something visible to the user, just trying to pick better term to use internally.

Comment: I don't think this is common enough for a specific word to exist for it, honestly.

Comment: Could you provide a sample sentence, please? It's not entirely clear what you want. Do you want something which describes/names the zeroth version? Or something which describes/names the *system* of using zero as the latest version? Do you need an adjective or a noun? I agree with @TobySpeight that it's uncommon, but someone might come up with something which fits your need.

Comment: That said, I can see the merit in always having a fixed number for the latest version. A frame challenge would be -- Since you have to renumber everything every time a new version 0 is issued, why not renumber them -1, -2, -3, so that the latest version is still the highest number?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Actually I am looking for a name for to give to a database column, nothing to use in a sentence. Still it seemed as more of an English language question rather than programming question.

Comment: This sounds like a file overwrite accident waiting to happen.

Comment: increment a number? Poor usage of that word....decreasing/increasing version numbers. https://perlmaven.com/consistent-version-numbers-of-modules

Comment: I'd probably see this as "back revisions" or "back versions" - that is, if the current document is "foo-0", then I'd probably refer to "foo-3" as "Foo, three revisions back" or "foo, three versions back".

Comment: We're used to the age system of labelling (as oerkelens points out) but there is always a a more fixed label for the entity ('Euphonia Gage', say, even if 'née Green'). As TH says, this could lead to confusion as all previous entries are frequently renamed. Not a typical labelling strategy.

Comment: The usual solution here is to have the version number count up, and then have a separate record pointing to the current version. That way version IDs are stable over time and you have less mutable state.

Comment: @michalsrb This is why we don't do naming questions. You can call your database column `Susan` and it would work just as well (even as a descriptor: "You need the document with the Susan value of zero"). The variety of answers demonstrates that the question is not clear, and I should have closed it when I originally commented. Please follow our [help for this sort of question](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and it can be re-opened. Invalidating an answer or several may be unavoidable.

Comment: @AndrewLeach — A database column named `Susan` would work just fine for the database, but not for the human querying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if we start with a version of a document, when a new version is published, the original one has a property that increases, we seem to be looking for something that increases over time.

I would say the most commonly used concept that fits that description is **age**.

Whether you measure that age in years (as with humans), days or *versions*, it always *does* increase over time, and gives an intuitive idea of the relevance of the version you are looking at.

If you are looking at a name for your database column, you could consider *version_age* of simply *age*, though the latter will require good documentation - then again, this kind of numbering *has* to be documented well anyway, since it is uncommon.

Also consider that if you have many versions, you have to update many records when you add a new version. This may or may not be give rise to a performance concern. (The positive pay-off is that finding the current version is slightly quicker than with traditional versioning.)

Comment: Yes, "age" is what came to mind for me.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be *exactly* what you're looking for but..

> Increment

Means to increase and the reverse of that is

> Decrement

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/decrement

Comment: This isn't really related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the date as the version number? This way the current document can always be version 0 and when it is replaced its version number is changed to its creation date and the new document assumes version 0. Then you wouldn't have to renumber every version in the DB and users wouldn't be confused if they have to refer to an older version, it will always be, say, 23042021. This has the additional advantage that you know for what period a particular version was valid.
As for a database column name, "version date" may be OK.

Answer (score -1):

How about something to do with **ancestry** or **pedigree**.

It seems that they latest is the newborn and the older versions are its **prior generations** or **ancestors**
Ancestor 1, Ancestor 2, etc